# Tailwind sidebar issues

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm new to tailwind, I tried making a sidebar and the main bar, the sidebar should be on the left while the main bar should be on the right but the sidebar is pushing the main bar content to the bottom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="flex-col w-full md:flex md:flex-row md:min-h-screen">
        <div @click.away="open = false" class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0 w-full text-gray-700 bg-white md:w-64 dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800" x-data="{ open: false }">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between flex-shrink-0 px-8 py-4">
                <a href="#" class="text-lg font-semibold tracking-widest text-gray-900 uppercase rounded-lg dark-mode:text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Flowtrail UI</a>
                <button class="rounded-lg md:hidden focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @click="open = !open">
                    <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="w-6 h-6">
                        <path x-show="!open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        <path x-show="open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
                <nav :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-grow px-4 pb-4 md:block md:pb-0 md:overflow-y-auto">
                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-gray-700 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">About</a>
                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Contact</a>
                    <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
                        <button @click="open = !open" class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:block hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                            <span>Dropdown</span>
                            <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                        </button>
                        <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg">
                            <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-700">
                                <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #1</a>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        </div>

        <!-- main bar -->
            <main class="m-2 p-8">
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
    </div>
    


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please, anyone should kindly help

Comment: Using the code you've provided in a clean L9 + Tailwind installation, it appears to work as expected. Check that whatever styles you're applying to your `{{ $slot }}` content is not conflicting and causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have the main, outside the tag

```
<body class="bg-gray-200">
  
  <div class="flex-col w-full md:flex md:flex-row md:min-h-screen md:justify-between">
    <div @click.away="open = false" class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-64 text-gray-700 bg-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800 flex-shrink-0" x-data="{ open: false }">
      <div class="flex-shrink-0 px-8 py-4 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
        <a href="#" class="text-lg font-semibold tracking-widest text-gray-900 uppercase rounded-lg dark-mode:text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">Flowtrail UI</a>
        <button class="rounded-lg md:hidden rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" @click="open = !open">
          <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="w-6 h-6">
            <path x-show="!open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM9 15a1 1 0 011-1h6a1 1 0 110 2h-6a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
            <path x-show="open" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <nav :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': !open}" class="flex-grow md:block px-4 pb-4 md:pb-0 md:overflow-y-auto">
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-200 rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-gray-700 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" 
        href="{{route('admin.categories.index')}}">Categorias</a>
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" 
        href="{{route('admin.menus.index')}}">Menu</a>
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" 
        href="{{route('admin.mesas.index')}}">Mesas</a>
        <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" 
        href="{{route('admin.reservation.index')}}">Reservacion</a>
        <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{ open: false }">
          <button @click="open = !open" class="flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:block hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
            <span>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</span>
            <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
          </button>
          <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg">
            <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
              <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#">Link #1</a>
               <!-- Authentication -->
               <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                @csrf

                <x-dropdown-link :href="route('logout')"
                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                    this.closest('form').submit();">
                    {{ __('Log Out') }}
                </x-dropdown-link>
            </form>

             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    
    <main class="m-2 p-8 w-full">
      {{ $slot }}

    </main>
   
</div>
  
    
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the width of the first div inside the parent div is not full and add md:justify-between in the parent div like this:

```
<div class="flex-col w-full md:flex md:flex-row md:min-h-screen md:justify-between">
    <div @click.away="open = false" class="flex flex-col flex-shrink-0 w-[50%] text-gray-700 bg-white md:w-64 dark-mode:text-gray-200 dark-mode:bg-gray-800" x-data="{ open: false }">
       <!-- side bar-->
    </div>
    <main class="m-2 p-8">
       <!-- main bar -->
       <p>Your logged in</p>
   </main>
</div>
```